# Realm query - sort child RealmList

Tags: java, realm, realm-list

I have a question. I have relationship 1:N (user : tasks). I need to query list of all Users where each user has list of his tasks - sorted by date (specified attribute).

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the users

```
RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
```

Then when you need the sorted list, get it from user

```
 User user = users.get(i);
 RealmResults<Task> tasks = user.getTasks().where().sort("date").findAll();
```

Answer (score -2):

`RealmList` needs `RealmObject`.
This means that `RealmList` can not create its sorted copy.
If you need sorting, you can use `Collections.sort(List)`or `Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`.

Comment: uh, `realmList.where().sort("blah").findAll()`